# Why is Gooey checkbox function not reacting to user input?

Tags: python, user-interface

I am building a GUI based on Gooey and I want to add a checkbox and store the value as True/False but I am getting the error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is the code I am using for the checkbox:

```
import pandas as pd
from gooey import Gooey, GooeyParser

@Gooey(program_name="DEPRECIATION",navigation='TABBED', header_bg_color = '#6aa2fc',default_size=(710, 700))
def parse_args():
    parser = GooeyParser()

    parser.add_argument('Useful_Life',
                        widget='CheckBox',
                        default = False,
                        action = "store_true",
                        help='Calculate depreciation based on Useful years')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_args()
    switch1 = args.Useful_Life
    print(switch1)
```

Am I missing something?

Reference:https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey/issues/148

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having the same issue with checkboxes. I get the error `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @SCool unfortunately no, I decided to use DropDown instead. Same functionality, just a different layout

Comment: I opened an issue on their github, and it's solved for me now. Looks like you need to ad a `--` to your `Useful_Life` string. So it should be `--Useful_Life`. See my issue here: https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey/issues/485